# c# to transform an unordered list into a series of textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

My SQL database is outputting a blob of html that looks something like this:

```
<ul><li>Test 1</li><li>Test 2</li></ul>
```

Which I would like to transform into a list of textboxes which look something like this:

```
<textarea>Test 1</textarea><textarea>Test 2</textarea>
```

How do I do this? I've tried parsing into XML but this doesn't seem to work and seems a lengthy way of doing things.

Comment: Does your database really store HTML? I think that's the root of your problem...

Comment: str = str.replace("<ul>","").replace("</ul>","").replace("<li>","<textarea>").replace("</li>","</textarea>");

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which makes it very easy to do things like this:

```
var nodes= doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name.StartsWith("li")).ToList();
```

You could then iterate over the collection and build your `TextArea`

```
foreach (HTML.HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    // ... build your text area here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the wording of your question, I am inferring that you are primarily looking for a way to access the DOM of a snippet of HTML. There may be other tools for this, but I can recommend Html Agility Pack which is available as a Nuget package (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Once you have the DOM structure loaded, you can access and modify it as you need, and you can generate output html as well.

This library is quite forgiving of poorly written HTML, so if your database values are less controlled (entered by users, for example), it is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks - I have tried this: `code` string TheRole = dr["TheRole"].ToString();

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(TheRole);

                var RolesList = doc.Root.Elements("li")
                                   .Select(element => element.Value)
                                   .ToList(); `code`  but the foreach then does not loop correctly - will have a look at htmlagility

Comment: Should this comment be on my answer ? `nodes` should contain a list of all of the `li` elements ...